# WooCommerce - update order item price and recalculate totals

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

What is the proper way to change order shipping item price and recalculate totals? I'm trying to do:

```
$order = new \WC_Order(2051);
foreach ($order->get_items('shipping') as $key => $item) {
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'cost',0);
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'total_tax',0);
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'taxes',[]);
}

$order->calculate_totals();
```

Which doesn't seem to work, and does not use WooCommerce datastore functions..

Answer (score 3):

Probably you already found a better way to do this since this question is quite old, but so far I could only make it work by getting the price difference manually and then using the method set_total from the order object:

```
$order = new \WC_Order(2051);
$diff = 0;
foreach ($order->get_items('shipping') as $key => $item) {
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'cost',0);
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'total_tax',0);
    wc_update_order_item_meta($key,'taxes',[]);
    $diff += $item->get_total();
}
$newTotal = $order->calculate_totals() - $diff;
$order->set_total($newTotal);
$order->save();
```

I will post this here because maybe it could be useful for someone. If you see this and you found a better / cleaner way to solve this I would like to see it :-).